# Minecraft done loading error 12.04 ubuntu. How to fix it?

Tags: games, minecraft

I want to buy minecraft and I decided first to go for the trial and see how it works. Installed oracle java and when I started the game it would always stuck at done loading. Deleted the bin folder in .minecraft, still the same issue. Deleted the .minecraft folder, still the same issue.

Has anyone experienced t;his issue on 12.04. Is there a way to fix it and enjoy the trial?
Below is my java version

java -version
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Who spreads these false rumors that Oracle Java is needed? In fact, it may be the cause of problems.

Comment: You should not use the oracle java. The default java works fine.

Comment: http://www.minecraft.net/download says 'also please use Sun's (i.e. Oracle's) JVM.'. The official Java performs WAY faster, all programmers know this.

Answer (score 3):

Try exiting Minecraft and re-launching it again. If it happens again, you will need to update the Lightweight Java Game Library files for Minecraft. To do that, do the following:

1) Download the latest version of [LWJGL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-game-lib/files/Official%20Releases/LWJGL%202.8.4/lwjgl-2.8.4.zip/download).

2) Extract the contents of the downloaded zip file.

3) Go into your Home folder and press **Ctrl + H** on your keyboard to view the hidden files and locate the **.minecraft** folder.

4) In the **.minecraft** folder, go to **bin** > **natives** folder. In that folder replace **libjinput-linux.so**, **libjinput-linux64.so**, **liblwjgl.so**, and **liblwjgl64.so** with the new files that you downloaded, which are located in the folder that was extracted from the downloaded zip file, **native** > **linux**.

5) Then in the .minecraft > bin folder, replace **jinput.jar**, **lwjgl.jar**, and **lwjgl_util.jar** with the files from the downloaded zip located in the **jar** folder.

Comment: Your answer make sense, but I cannot get it works...